# How to derive the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Stochastic Integral Equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, integration, stochastic-integrals, brownian-motion

I have a question regarding the Ornstein -Uhlenbeck process. We have a simplified version with Stochastic Integral Equation: $X_t=-a\int^t_0 X_s\,ds +B_t$. B is the Brownian motion.

And its analytic solution is $X_t=e^{-at}\int^t_0 e^{as}\,dB_s$.

How do I prove that this is the case? I know that $e^{-at}=-a\int^t_0 e^{-as}\,ds$ and that I'm somehow supposed to make use of this result but I am still unable to get from the analytic solution to the integral equation.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to check if solution is correct, why not apply Ito formula? In the case you wonder how the analytic solution was obtained from the integral equation - that's a bit more elaborate.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to apply Ito's formula? Sorry I'm not very good with this subject. I know that Ito formula is $f(B_t)-f(B_0)=\int^t_0 f'(B_u)\,dB_u+{1/2}\int^t_0 f''(B_u)\,du$ but I don't know what function should f(x) be.

Comment: No, its in my lecture notes. I just can't understand that bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Ito formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D's_lemma), for $\mathrm{d} X_t = - a X_t \mathrm{d} t + \mathrm{d} B_t$, you need is:
$$
   \mathrm{d}\left( f(t, X_t) \right) =
      \left(  \partial_t f(t,X_t) - a X_t \partial_x f(t,X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} f(t,X_t) \right) \mathrm{d} t + 
      \left( \partial_x f(t,X_t) \right) \mathrm{d} B_t
$$

**HINT**: use $f(t,X_t) = \mathrm{e}^{a t} X_t$.

Edit 9/8/2018: Added $X_t$ to formula

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll go work on it.

Comment: from where $- a X_t \partial_x f(t,X_t) $ come from?

Comment: From Ito formula. Please review the linked article.